# Media files multiple select in browser using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I know you can select multiple files like this using "Jquery":

```
selection.map( function( attachment ) {
    attachment = attachment.toJSON();
    $("#something").after("<img src=" +attachment.url+">");
});
```

but how is selecting multiple files done with Angular.js

Comment: It's a jQuery code using `map` the wrong way (Nothing is returned by the callback function) - So where is your angularjs code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am asking, how is it done in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet, we can assume that you have an array `selection` that look something like this:

```
$scope.selection = [
    {url: 'http://......', otherKey: 'otherValue1'},
    {url: 'http://......', otherKey: 'otherValue2'},
    .....
];
```

And you're appending image to a DIV with ID `#something`. The view should contain `ngRepeat` for iterating the objects inside `selection` and IMG tag with `ngSrc` with the url of each image. Something like:

```
<div id="something">
    <img ng-repeat="img in selection" ng-src="{{ img.url }}" />
</div>
```

I'm assuming you know how to add a controller and you learned how to bing properties from the controller to the view using `$scope`.